# Deploying META-INF directory of a project listed in a Deployment Assembly

Tags: eclipse-wtp, meta-inf

I have a project that has some data in the META-INF folder that it needs for proper functioning. Specifically, it has a services sub-directory, with a service file in it.

When I add that project to the Web Deployment Assembly list and publish the application, resulting jar file has no META-INF directory. There is also no option in the Java Build Path dialog to add that directory to the export.

As a work-around, I can export the project to the jar file manually and put it into WEB-INF/lib directory, but I have to do that on every change so I was wondering if there was any way to automate the process.

Answer (score 1):

My experience: META-INF folder should be inside one of source folders. For example, I have "config" and "source/java" source folders. I put META-INF into config, and my web application deploys smoothly.

Comment: Weird, shouldn't it be at the same level as WEB-INF ?